# Why is std::copy throwing an error vector iterator + offset out of range and not able to copy

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I was trying to copy an int array into std::vector of int and I am seeing some unusual behavior. So I have an array as defined as below.

```
int myarray[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
```

and I tried copying the above array into vector using different methods as below which throws errors.

1) Using reserve

```
std::vector<int> vec1;
vec1.reserve(10);
std::copy(myarray, myarray+10,vec1.begin() );
```

This throws an **`error`** in VS 2013 which is :-

```
vector iterator + offset out of range
```

2) By defining size

```
std::vector<int> vec2(10);
std::copy(myarray, myarray+10,vec2.begin() );
```

Which `successfully copies the array` into the vector.

3) Just declaring the vector .

```
std::vector<int> vec3;
std::copy(myarray, myarray+10,vec3.begin() );
```

Which also throws an **`error`**

```
vector iterator + offset out of range
```

Also searching over the internet I found that `std::back_inserter` could be used, but I don't know what difference it would make.

Can some please explain the difference between all the three methods and whats going wrong in 1 and 3.

Comment: Also I did read if the vector doesn't already have a size equal to or greater than the size of the array: copy doesn't call push_back, it performs a direct assignment on this link https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/120258/copy-an-arrays-contents-into-a-vector-stl. How much is this correct.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `vec1.reserve(10);` use `vec1.resize(10);`

`std::vector::reserve` would increase the capacity of vector but the size remains same. It requests that the vector capacity be at least enough to contain n elements.

On the other hand, `std::vector::resize` resizes the container so that it contains n elements

Comment: Correct.  But note that the whole thing can be avoided: just do `vector<int> vec(myarray, myarray+10)` and you're done in one line.

Comment: is it that unless and until I declare the size of the vector `std::copy` is not going to copy.

Comment: @JohnZwinck isn't the method you suggested only works in C++11 and above.

Comment: @JohnZwinck `vector<int> vec(myarray, myarray+10)` does this works with iterators also say if I pass the `begin()` and `end()`.

Comment: @Surfing_SO Yes it does

Answer (score 1):

As @Mohit Jain's answer shows `resize` would help. But that initializes the vector which is not needed. For integers it might not be a problem but for big objects it's definitely a performance overhead.

`reserve` can help here if you use `std::copy` as shown below.

```
std::vector<int> vec2(10);
vec2.reserve(10);
std::copy(myarray, myarray+10, std::back_inserter(vec));
```

BTW, you can also copy the contents of the array to the vector during the construction of the vector itself.

```
std::vector<int> vec2 ( myarray, myarray + 10);
```